# Why could a no-op change the optimization result?

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I'm modifying a part of a fairly large tool that uses PyTorch to optimize some parameters. I noticed that if I add this line to the code, the results are getting worse:

```
self.gammas = self.gammas.unsqueeze(2).squeeze(2)
```

`self.gammas` is a tensor that at this point only contains zeros, and will later be optimized.

Unfortunately, I'm not able to condense the project into a small example, but are there general reasons why this no-op might have an impact on the optimization process?

I've made sure that the process is deterministic: If I run the code multiple times both with an without the modification, the results are consistent.

Comment: If the `tensor` has a batch size of `1` then `squeeze` will remove the batch dimension which may lead to unexpected errors. Besides that, why is it that `self.gammas` is `squeeze`d and `unsqueeze`d together on the same dimension? That might be causing side effects.

Comment: @OriYardenPhD `self.gammas` has shape `(2, 2)` before and after the manipulation. The unsqueeze + squeeze combination is an artifact of how the code is structured, depending on the configuration other stuff might happen in between. But in my case, it's just this combination. If I remove it entirely, the results change. What kind of side effects do you mean? I would expect this to be a no-op, is this incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

One side-effect of this operation is that it creates a copy of `self.gammas`. Consider the following script:

```
betas = torch.ones(2, 3)
gammas = betas
# gammas = gammas.unsqueeze(2).squeeze(2)

betas.data = torch.clamp(betas.data, min=2.0)

assert torch.all(gammas == 2.0)
```

This code will run successfully. However, if you uncomment line three, `gammas` will no longer point to the same object as `betas`, so the increase of the values in `betas` will not be reflected by `gammas`.